# limit points of ${x}$ in a $T_0$ space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a $T_0$ topology space. How do I prove that for every element $x\in X$ the set of limit points of ${x}$ is a union of closed sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: By *the set of limit points of* $x$ I’m assuming that you mean the set $L=\big(\operatorname{cl}\{x\}\big)\setminus\{x\}$. Let $y\in L$.

- Show that $\operatorname{cl}\{y\}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}\{x\}$.
- Use the fact that $X$ is $T_0$ to show that $x\notin\operatorname{cl}\{y\}$ and hence $\operatorname{cl}\{y\}\subseteq L$.